# Filter category products by Attribute Set Id

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework, magento-1.9

I have created a custom module which rewrite the `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` class, now I want to filter Category product collection by attribute_set_id. Below is my code for this:

```
 protected function _getProductCollection()
        {
            if (is_null($this->_productCollection)) {
                $layer = $this->getLayer();
                /* @var $layer Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer */
                if ($this->getShowRootCategory()) {
                    $this->setCategoryId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId());
                }

                // if this is a product view page
                if (Mage::registry('product')) {
                    // get collection of categories this product is associated with
                    $categories = Mage::registry('product')->getCategoryCollection()
                        ->setPage(1, 1)
                        ->load();
                    // if the product is associated with any category
                    if ($categories->count()) {
                        // show products from this category
                        $this->setCategoryId(current($categories->getIterator()));
                    }
                }

                $origCategory = null;
                if ($this->getCategoryId()) {
                    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
                    if ($category->getId()) {
                        $origCategory = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
                        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category);
                        $this->addModelTags($category);
                    }
                }
                $this->_productCollection = $layer->getProductCollection();

                /** Filter I used to filter collection by attribute_set_id**/               
                $this->_productCollection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_set_id', array('eq' => 4));
                $this->prepareSortableFieldsByCategory($layer->getCurrentCategory());

                if ($origCategory) {
                    $layer->setCurrentCategory($origCategory);
                }
            }

            return $this->_productCollection;
        }
```

but after that I am getting below error:

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column
>   'e.attribute_set_id' in 'where clause',